# why my mysql keep shutting down previously it was working fine

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, innodb, mariadb-10.4

why my mysql keep shutting down previously it was working fine just giving some js error on browser but still working that time, now it is keep shutting down

here's the error log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnYp9.png)

Comment: Please post the log here instead of image.  That said, I don't see any errors.  Have you reviewed this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/crashing.html ?

Comment: why is the innodb buffer pool size so small? There's no logs indicating shutdown, did the OS hard kill the process.

Comment: How much RAM in the machine (or VM)?